# Entity query to select current dates

Tags: 7, datetime, database

The situation: I have a drupal 7 node which has a date field. This uses the date module and it has multiple values each with a start and end date.

The problem is that I want to query drupal for all nodes where the current date is between the start and end dates of a single delta.

The entity query I have at the moment doesn't check the same value for both start and end dates.

For example if the first date value started 1/1/2013 and ended 30/1/2013 and if there was a second value which started 1/12/2013 and ended 30/12/2013. Using the current date of today 11/10/2013 this node should NOT be fetched. However under the query below it is because there is a start date in the past and an end date in the future, even though they're not from the same field delta.

```
  $current_date = date("Y-m-d");

  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', RD_PRIZE_DRAW_NODE_TYPE);
    ->fieldCondition('field_rd_prize_draw_dates', 'value', $current_date, '<=')
    ->fieldCondition('field_rd_prize_draw_dates', 'value2', $current_date, '>=');
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 4):

Having actually read the [fieldCondition documentation](https://api.drupal.org/comment/11639#comment-11639) the fourth property turns out to be $delta_group which allows specifying dependent conditions. So it turns out all I needed was the below:

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', RD_PRIZE_DRAW_NODE_TYPE);
    ->fieldCondition('field_rd_prize_draw_dates', 'value', $current_date, '<=', 1)
    ->fieldCondition('field_rd_prize_draw_dates', 'value2', $current_date, '>=', 1);
    ->execute();
```